# jQuery Object has no method 'XXX'

Tags: jquery

I am working on a page where I can crop a smaller image out of a larger one.  I have a prototype working at this url:

http://www.omnicom-innovations.com/ImageExample.aspx

Now, I'm trying to take that same code and put it into another web site.  I have references to the same .js / .css files.

However, when I attempt to crop the image, I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'replace'

jquery.min.js : Line 12

I have seen this error and I've attempted to Google it but I haven't had much success.  My understanding of this error is that:

a.  The object hasn't completely loaded which is why there would be no replace method.

What I'm trying to find out is, is there some sort of order that the javascript files have to be loaded?  Why would this error occur in one page and not another?  What I'm looking for is some sort of ideas (or roadmap), so if this error occurs again, I can try this, try that, etc...

Comment: It is indeed important what order the files are listed. If one is dependent on another, it should be listed below that one.

Comment: It could also be that the new page already has jquery included on it and you added it again when you copied in your code. ( I was puzzled by the same error today and that was what caused it for me.)